# So, should "Thailand" be pronounced as /ˈtaɪ.lænd/ or /ˈθaɪ.lænd/?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

OK, I searched on the Internet and found that online dictionaries give the following pronunciation of *Thailand* as ***/ˈtaɪ.lænd/***.

[Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thailand) says

> *noun* /ˈtaɪ.lænd/

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Thailand?q=thailand) says:

> Pronunciation: /ˈtʌɪland/

However, based on the audio excerpts, I feel that *Thailand* should be pronounced as */ˈθaɪ.lænd/*.

I managed to record myself pronouncing "*Thailand*" as:

1. */ˈtaɪ.lænd/* (you can hear the audio file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLT1RDTFYyQVZnSnM/view?usp=sharing) )
2. */ˈθaɪ.lænd/* (you can hear the audio file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9o9iLQ2SktLazlRR29adUxER0U/view?usp=sharing) )

I think some dictionaries do not have the correct pronunciation.

So, should "*Thailand*" be pronounced as /*ˈtaɪ.lænd*/ or /*ˈθaɪ.lænd*/?

Extra info: Now listen to this video and hear the difference between **thigh** /*θʌɪ*/ and  **tie** /*tʌɪ*/. See at 0:46 on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewQyUi4QvC0)

Comment: #2 is closer to the way I pronounce it (and have since about 5th grade).  It's as if it's spelled "tie-land" rather than "thigh-land".

Comment: I don't understand why you are questioning their pronunciation:  First, they all agree that it's a /t/ but then you say "based on the sound they pronounce"?  Are you just saying that because "Thailand" starts with a TH you think it should be /θ/ ?

Comment: Also I have never heard anybody ever say "thigh-land", it is always "tie-land".  (Including my sister-in-law, who is from Thailand.)

Comment: You've got these two sounds mixed up. The file you name "Thailand T.wma" uses /θ/, the one you name "Thailand Th.wma" uses /t/. And the recordings at your two dictionary links use /t/.

Comment: Yes, I was about to say the two may be mixed up.  I thought the theta in IPA was the "th" sound (I've never studied it), but the first recording is saying "thigh-land" and the second (sort of) "tie-land".

Comment: @StoneyB, I have just checked the files, there is no mixed-up here.

Comment: I just checked again.  The first recording is saying "thigh-land", the second is saying "tie-land".

Comment: You've got them labeled backward. The sound usually spelled ‹th›, as in *thin* or *thing*, is IPA /θ/, the voiceless interdental fricative. And the sound usually spelled ‹t›, as in *tin* or *tie*, is IPA /t/, the voiceless alveolar stop. /t/ is the sound used in English *Thailand*, the sound represented as /t/ and pronounced as /t/ in the dictionaries to which you link.

Comment: @StoneyB, the /θ/ in /ˈθaɪ.lænd/ is the same as /θ/ in thing /θɪŋ/

Comment: If we pronounced it as /ˈθaɪ.lænd/ it would be the same thing; but although we **spell** it that way, we don't **pronounce** it that way, we pronounce it as /ˈ**t**aɪ.lænd/

Comment: "Thailand T.wma" file is /ˈtaɪ.lænd/  & "Thailand Th.wma" file is /ˈθaɪ.lænd/

Comment: No, they're not. You've got them backwards. --May I ask what your native tongue is? I suspect you are confusing aspirate /t/ with fricative /θ/.

Comment: /θ/ & /t/ are not the same. Ex /*ˈθiː.sɪs*/ thesis and /*tiː*/ tea

Comment: I speak Vietnamese

Comment: That's right. But the file which you name "Thailand Th.wma" uses /t/, not /θ/.

Comment: So, I am pronouncing incorrectly?

Comment: You are pronouncing both correctly. You are *labeling* them incorrectly.

Comment: I'm recalling that (many years ago) I observed Vietnamese people essentially mixing up the "t" and "th" sounds.  This likely happens when you focus on the wrong aspects of the sound when trying to duplicate it, since you don't know which aspects of an individual sound are the distinctive ones that differentiate it from similar sounds (and likely your ears aren't "tuned" to detect the critical differences).

Comment: /θ/ is the sound which does not exist in your language: a continuant. Put your tongue between your teeth and breathe out--you may continue the sound as long as your breath holds out. /t/ is a stop, a single burst of sound. You have two versions in your language, which you spell ‹t› and ‹th›. We use both, in different contexts, but we hear them as a single sound: /t/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @StoneyB "You have two versions in your language, which you spell ‹t› and ‹th›. We use both, in different contexts, but we hear them as a single sound: /t/." what do you mean? DO you mean /t/ & /θ/ sounds the same or you do not distinguish /t/ & /θ/?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, I do not have a misunderstanding. Ok, now look at this video and hear the difference between **thigh** /*θʌɪ*/ & **tie** /*tʌɪ*/. See at 0:46 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewQyUi4QvC0. <pre>Do you see the difference?</pre>

Comment: I *know* the difference between /θ/ and /t/ sounds. But I think you are under the impression that words that contain the letters **th** are always pronounced   /θ/, this is not true. There are three possible pronunciations:  **/θ/** e.g. [thin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thin); **/t/** e.g [*thyme*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thyme) and **/ð/** e.g. [*mother*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mother)

Comment: Please support your theory that there are some dictionaries that provide the **incorrect* pronunciation of Thailand. Don't confuse spelling with pronunciation, which is where I think your confusion lies. In all the dictionaries I looked up, the pronunciation of  *Thailand* is /ˈtʌɪland/, *[tahy-land, -luh nd]*, /ˈtaɪˌlænd/, and (tī′lănd′, -lənd),

Comment: @Mary-, I never had any mixed-up like that. /*θʌɪ*/ & tie /*tʌɪ*/ are so similar. That is why I am asking about. I always use dictionary to check for the pronunciation

Comment: Anh besides, many words in dictionary does not have correct IPA. Different dictionary may have different IPA. That is why I asked the question

Comment: You continue to insist that your two recordings are not effectively reversed.  But everyone is telling you they are.  I'd suggest you find someone who speaks English fairly well and have them listen to what you're saying.

Comment: @user105551 To a native English speaker /θ/ and /t/ are *very* different. What we don't distinguish is /t/ and /tʰ/, which I read are different phonemes in Vietnamese.

Comment: @StoneyB They’re not backwards as such—he’s just pronouncing English /t/ as a Vietnamese /t/ (i.e., a dental, unaspirated [t̪], rather than the normal English alveolar, aspirated [t͇ʰ]), and /th/ as a Vietnamese /tʰ/ (i.e., a dental, aspirated stop [t̪ʰ], rather than the normal English interdental fricative [θ]). So no, he’s not pronouncing either ‘correctly’.

Comment: @user105551 You are misunderstanding IPA. In the file _Thailand T_, you are pronouncing more or less [ˈt̪aɪlæːnd], and in the file _Thailand Th_, you are pronouncing more or less [ˈt̪ʰaɪlæːnd]. **You do not say the sound [θ] in either file at all.** The two sounds you pronounce in your files, [t̪] and [t̪ʰ], are indeed very similar. They are different phonemes in Vietnamese, but _not_ in English. English always uses [tʰ] at the beginning of a stressed syllable (as in _Thailand_) and [t ~ ɾ] in other environments, but they are the same sound. [θ] is a completely different and unrelated sound.

Comment: Both [t] and [tʰ] are **plosives/stops**: the tongue stops the air completely from coming out of your mouth, just like with [p] and [k]. [θ] is a different matter: it’s an unvoiced _fricative_, just like [f] and [s], which is the only unvoiced fricatives Vietnamese has. The air does not stop at all: it keeps flowing between your tongue and your upper teeth. In fact, to you as a Vietnamese speaker, [f] and [θ] probably sound almost exactly the same. So if you say [θaɪlænd], it should sound very, very similar to [faɪlænd] to you.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you sure? My ear's no longer up to discriminating between dental and alveolar /t/, but OP's "Thailand T" has four readings which to my ear get progressively longer spirant quality.

Comment: @StoneyB I hear them very clearly as completely unaspirated (with so little VOT that they almost become voiced) dental or even interdental stops. Now that I listen again, I do hear a slight amount of spirantisation on the last one, but it sounds distinctly voiced to me—like [t̪͡ð] or something. But the plosivity is by far the more salient feature to my ear.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hokey-dokey. Guess I'm getting old.

Comment: @Janus, I am very happy with your explanation. I did not know that /*t*/ in English should be pronounced similarly as /*th*/ in Vietnamese. Vietnamese has a very clear /*t*/ sound and seem English do not have that clear /*t*/ but rather they pronounce like /*th*/. Besides, when I pronounce /*θ*/, I did actually put my tongue between my upper and lower teeth, but seem I did aspirate a lot and that somehow made my  /*θ*/ sound like /*th*/. So, putting the tongue between upper and lower teeth is not the key element in producing /*θ*/, we must do not aspirate when making /*θ*/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you should post an answer.

Comment: @Janus, I am very happy if you could post an answer cos it can help Vietnamese speaker a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any ambiguity I'd use the first pronunciation (the one with the t sound) because almost every single dictionary (including Jones pronouncing dictionary) says it's ***t*** in the transcription

Comment: Listen to the recordings and see if you still feel the same way.

Comment: @Alex, are you native English speaker?

Comment: Listen it's English not Vietnamese most people pronounce it with a t sound

Comment: I am I don't get it what's the problem?

Comment: @user105551 yes I am did you want to ask something?